Image of unit circle under $f(w) = \frac{1}{w + w^2}$?
How to find the image of the unit circle under $f(w) = \frac{1}{w + w^2}$?
Let $w = u + iv$ with $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, then
$$
f(w) = \frac{u^2 - v^2 + u}{(2uv + v)^2 + (u^2 - v^2 + u)^2} - i \frac{2uv + v}{(2uv + v)^2 + (u^2 - v^2 + u)^2}. $$
I am stuck.
Edit : I have plotted $f(\exp(2i\pi/n))$ for $n = 100$. It's look like a cubic curve.


Wouldn't $w=e^{i\theta}$ be a more natural substitution here?

Your figure is correct. If you used a language like Matlab, which handles complex numbers seamlessly, you would not have to go through all these machinations. The pseudo-code is w=exp(i*\theta); z=1./(w+w.^2); plot(z)

I add a complete answer with the polar form. Your shape is good here !

$$\forall t\notin(1+2\Bbb Z)\pi,\quad f(e^{it})=\frac{e^{-3it/2}}{2\cos(t/2)}$$
hence the image of the unit circle (minus $w=-1$ of course) under $f$ is the trisectrix of Maclaurin with polar equation
$$\rho=\frac{1/2}{\cos\frac\theta3}$$ $(\theta\notin\frac{3\pi}2(1+2\Bbb Z)).$

Very nice on the complex form. I would only suggest that $t\in(-\pi,\pi)$ to avoid the singularities. In addition, from your link, you should have $\rho=2\cos\frac{t}{3}$, but I find that that is not the same as the complex function.

In order to plot the transform $\mathcal{C}_1$ unit circle
Using polar coordinates :
$$ f(w)=e^{i\theta}=u+iv $$ as suggested in the comments.
$$f(w)=\dfrac{1}{e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{3i\theta/2}}\dfrac{1}{e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta/2}}=\dfrac{1}{e^{3i\theta/2}}\dfrac{1}{2\cos(\theta/2)}$$
From Wolfram Alpha gives real and imaginary parts of $f(\theta)$ :

Then the modulus and argument of $f(\theta)$ is  :
$$ \rho(\theta)= \dfrac{1}{2\cos(\theta/2)} $$
$$ \alpha(\theta) = - 3\theta/2 $$


The final form
With the polar equation :
$$ \rho(\alpha)=\dfrac{1}{2\cos(\alpha/3)}$$
Ploting from $\alpha=0$ to $\alpha=3\pi$ in order to get $\theta=2\alpha/3$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. Noting that the minus do not change the plot since $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and we plot on a whole period of $\cos$  (whole circle)
The final transformed circle is :


$$\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}}\ne\frac{1}{e^{3i\theta/2}}\frac{1}{e^{-i\theta}+e^{i\theta}}$$

I mod and correct it with graphs. Please undo downvote if you have.

$$\frac{1}{e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta/2}}\ne\frac{2}{\cos(\theta/2)}$$

Thx I correct the things now

Not sure what exact form you´re looking for, but you could take the substitution mentioned in the comment, and compute the Real and Imaginary part of $\frac{1}{w+w^2}=\frac{\exp(-i\theta)}{1+\exp(i\theta)}$, and then plot:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1/2 + \cos(\theta) \\
- 1/2 sec(\theta/2) \sin((3 \theta)/2)
\end{pmatrix}$$ for $\theta\in [0, 2\pi)$.
[Image Edited!]


Something is wrong with your calculations, since $-1$ is in the image, but is not in your graph.

@jjagmath yes thank you I had -1/2*cos(theta), when I made the plot, now it should be correct.

If this is a parametric plot, I'd suggest plotting from $\theta=-\pi$ to $\pi$ instead to avoid the artificial line at $\operatorname{Re}f(w)=-3/2$

Not a complete answer...
$$z=\frac1{w+w^2}=\frac{w^{-\frac32}}{w^{\frac12}+w^{-\frac12}}$$
Let $w=e^{i\theta}$, $$0\leq\theta<2\pi.$$ Then, $z=x+iy$  where
$$x=\frac{\cos\frac32\theta}{2\cos\frac\theta2}$$
(Note that $x$ can be simplified to $x=\cos\theta-\frac12$)
$$y=-\frac{\sin\frac32\theta}{2\cos\frac\theta2}
$$
And
$$x^2+y^2=\frac1{4\cos^2\frac\theta2}=\frac1{2\cos\theta+2}$$
We have
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac1{\sqrt2\sqrt{\cos\theta+1}}$$
where $\theta\neq\pi.$ But, this is not polar coordinates version of the curve. It does not help for plotting too much. But, it tells that minumum, maximum of $r$ is $\frac12$, $\infty$, respectively.
Since $\cos\theta=2x+1$, the curve in cartesian coordinates is given by
$$(2x+3)(x^2+y^2)=1.$$
We can change it to polar coordinates from this equation. After $x\to x-1$ shifting, we get
$$r=2\cos\theta-\frac12\sec\theta.$$
At the begining making a scaling $t\to\frac{2t}3$, we see that the curve is $r=\frac12\sec\frac\theta 3$ as noted by Anne Bauval. She also noticed that this is a trisetrix and gave references.

Your mistake is using $\theta$ for two different things:  $\theta$ is the angle for the parametrization of the original circle, not the angle in polar coordinates of the transformed curve.

@jjagmath Yes. But, $r$ is ok.
